# Checking if RW() = ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift

Tags: r, time-series, arima, random-walk

I am trying to confirm the following statement that in R fable package: `RW() returns a random walk model, which is equivalent to an ARIMA(0,1,0) model with an optional drift coefficient included using drift()`
[rdrr link](https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverts/fable/man/RW.html)

Here is my example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(fpp3)


x <- seq(1,50, by = 1)
y <- 0.5*x + sin(x)
df <- data.frame(rn = x, value = y)

fit_RW <- df %>% 
  as_tsibble(.,index=rn) %>%
  model(drift = RW()) 

fc_RW <- fit_RW %>% forecast(h=10) %>% pull(.mean)
```

produces constant vector:

```
24.73763 24.73763 24.73763 24.73763 24.73763 24.73763
24.73763 24.73763 24.73763 24.73763
```

Now ARIMA:

```
fit_ARIMA <- df %>% 
  as_tsibble(., index =rn) %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(value ~ pdq(0,1,0))) 

fc_ARIMA <- fit_ARIMA %>% forecast(h=10) %>% pull(.mean)
```

produces:

```
25.21510 25.69257 26.17004 26.64752 27.12499 27.60246 28.07993 28.55741
29.03488 29.51235
```

This is clearly different. I also tried the following:

```
arima = ARIMA(value ~ pdq(0,1,0) + drift())
arima = ARIMA(value ~ 1 + pdq(0,1,0))
```

They either generate error or return something else.

Comment: If you could change your code to base R, you might stand a better chance to get useful answers. I personally consider the tidyverse a completely unnecessary additional hurdle for people learning R, and have a visceral reaction when confronted with it. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, Thank you,  I borrowed it from official fable documentation, it will take me awhile to convert to plain R

Comment: Your ARIMA model includes a drift parameter. If you want to omit it, specify the model as `value ~ 0 + pdq(0,1,0)`

Comment: @RobHyndman thank you so much! The description of RW() from my link is a bit confusing then. It looks like RW is Y_t = Y_{t-1}, rather than Y_t = c+ Y_{t-1}

Comment: That is correct for RW. My comment was about ARIMA.